# Beginner question: need help with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

Here is what I am working on.

http://jsfiddle.net/yfcZN/

What I want is padding of text that is inside of the  "P" tag like we do cell padding in "TD" tag.

I changed this code line,

```
text.css({ position: 'absolute', top: '57px' }).hide();
```

to

```
text.css({ position: 'absolute', top: '57px', paddingTop: 10px}).hide();
```

but it's not making any difference. What property is there to achieve what I want? I only found this "padding" one.

**[EDIT]
Thanks, all. I didn't give single quotes, silly mistake. Please check Mark's comment and my response to it. How can I fix it ?**

Comment: `10px` without quotes is not a valid Javascript value.

Comment: it makes a difference in FF (the padding does work as you have written it..except that you need quotes around '10px'.... but that whole hovering over thing behaves really wonk, keeps opening and closing if you trigger it a certain way.

Comment: @Mark : I know,right? need to figure out how to fix that..I tried changing "slideDown("fast");" to  "slow" but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to second question: Change `var box = $(this);` to `var box = $('h2',this);`.

Comment: This isn't really working coz as soon as a move my mouse over the text in the text bow that appears, it slides up again..earlier it would stay in place..actually I will be adding links and button inside this text box later so need it to stay..erm..hope its not confusing...but srsly what MArk pointed out IS annoying...how do I solve it ?

Comment: ah, in that case you have to make sure the `<p>` and the `<h2>` are connected. Now the gap between them makes your mouse leave and re-enter the hover area. I'll try and find a solution, hold on

Comment: You can fix the gap by making the text div touch the h2. That way there's no gap that makes you lose focus of the hover. To keep a white area between the two divs you could use a white border of 10px (or whatever) on top of the text div.  http://jsfiddle.net/yfcZN/7/

Answer (score 1):

Here, this seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/yfcZN/4/.